# How to fix the entropy pool issue with RHEL 5.x

Tags: rhel5, entropy-pool, hp-server-automation

RHEL 5.x has an [entropy-generation](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=117218) problem (held-over from kernel [2.4](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=118921)). Following directions from [here](http://www.vglug.info/how-increase-entropy-pool-2-6-kernel-rhel-fedora-system-without-keyboard-mouse) has produced little-to-no results:

> How to increase entropy pool on a 2.6 kernel RHEL/Fedora system without keyboard/mouse.
>
> A good source of entropy is needed for random number generation. This affects services that go via SSL amongst other things. In 2.6 kernels the entropy sources of a system are keyboard, mouse and some IRQ interrupts.
>   There are two random number sources on linux - /dev/random and /dev/urandom. /dev/random will block if there is nothing left in the entropy bit bucket. If your system does not have keyboard and mouse, you can use 'rngd' daemon to perform the task.
>   You can see the entropy valu using following command.
>
> ```
>     #cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail
> ```
>
> Now, start the 'rngd' daemon using following command and monitor the entropy on the system.
>
> ```
>     #rngd -r /dev/urandom -o /dev/random -f -t 1
>     #watch -n 1 cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail
> ```

What other fixes are available for this issue?

---

#### background

There is a known issue (on HP's side) with one component in the current version of Server Automation that takes a long time to startup due to a small entropy pool on RHEL 5. I'm trying to find a workaround until/unless it's fixed on the vendor's part.

Comment: Where does it say in your links that this affects 2.6 as well?

Comment: If you need lots of entropy, you could [buy more](http://www.entropykey.co.uk/).  See also: http://vincentsanders.blogspot.com/2011/08/year-of-entropy.html

Comment: @embobo - in the quoted segment for what I have already tried (from http://www.vglug.info/how-increase-entropy-pool-2-6-kernel-rhel-fedora-system-without-keyboard-mouse)

Comment: @warren, You really haven't made it clear what the problem is.  Do you actually need more entropy for something, or are you just worried about this.  So you ran those two commands, did anything change at all?  Are you still not getting enough entropy?  Or what.

Comment: @Zoredache : yes - I need more entropy in the pool for SSL-based components to an application I'm running; startup times *should* be on the order of 10-15 minutes, but on RHEL 5 it's upwards of 20 due to the entropy issue. And I thought I had made it clear that running `rngd` hadn't helped ("little-to-no results")

Comment: No, that doesn't make it very clear.  I was hoping you would say something like while I am doing nnn the output of `cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail` tends to be at or near zero constantly, but when the system is idle it tends to be around ~140.  Is it not refilling at all? Or is it just refilling to slowly for your needs.

Comment: @Zoredache - ahh ... the entropy pool actually *falls* while running the `rngd` tool as directed in the above quote

Comment: @warren let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1159/discussion-between-zoredache-and-warren)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also found this article, "[Cut your WebLogic startup time in half on Linux](http://www.go-integral.com/blog/%5Buser-raw%5D/cut-your-weblogic-startup-time-half-linux)", via a [coworker](http://theexceptioncatcher.com/blog/2012/11/really-cool-things-ive-learned-this-week-r-random-numbers-java-hypervisiors-and-fan-maintenance) this week.

The problem is worse in VMs than on physical machines because there is a lack of "driver noise".

#### update 31 Mar 2016

You can [also](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-additional-entropy-for-cloud-servers-using-haveged) run `haveged`. Or [try](http://www.finnie.org/software/twuewand) `twuewand`.

Answer (score 3):

As has been pointed out, colocated servers, lacking that random human being to create entropy, generally don't have much of it to spare.  If you have a physical server with a spare USB port, and a demonstrable need for high-grade entropy, you could do worse than get yourself an [Entropy Key](http://www.entropykey.co.uk/).  I don't normally recommend specific products on SF, but I rather like this one, and it does the job nicely.

Here's the depth of my pool before fitting the key:
[image: pool depth before key]

and here's the pool after:
[image: pool depth after key]

Declaration of interest: I have no connection with the makers except that I bought one of their products, at full price, and like it.

**Edit** (July 2015): the Entropy Key website has for some time said that they're out of stock, and they don't know when they'll have more made.  However, [OneRNG, a project to make a completely-open, verifiable, USB-connected entropy generator](http://onerng.info/), was fully funded on kickstarter, and at the time of writing intends to start selling them via a webstore once their kickstarter obligations are fulfilled.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how much entropy you need, but you could use the [HTTP API on random.org](http://www.random.org/clients/http/) to feed entropy into your system (try [rand_add](http://egd.sourceforge.net/)).  Or you could use something like the [Entropy Gathering Daemon](http://egd.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: From a security point of view, using publicly observable (or even changeable) random sources is not a good idea.

Comment: You're right.  If warren wanted to use the random.org API for business use, I would recommend using HTTPS and paying for the random.org service to establish trust through a financal and legal agreement.

Answer (score 1):

Change the t parameter to .1 or .001