# Haveged on Cloud Linux

Tags: linux, redhat, yum, entropy-pool, cloudlinux

I am trying to figure out how to install haveged on [Cloud Linux](https://cloudlinux.com). It doesn't seem to be avail in the repo, and trying to a do a make install does not work. My question is:

Is haveged compatible with CL, and if so, is there a repo I can simply add to install it?

All of the directions I have read on shows to simply yum install it, but it's not available on CL repos. Thats why I am not sure if it's compatible. I am trying to generate entropy on a server I cannot plug anything into.

Answer (score 1):

I've not run Cloud Linux, but this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-additional-entropy-for-cloud-servers-using-haveged) from Digital Ocean shows how to install it from source:

> visit the [download page](http://www.issihosts.com/haveged/downloads.html) and choose the latest release tarball (1.7a at the time of this writing). After downloading the tarball, untar it into your current working directory:

```
# tar zxvf /path/to/haveged-x.x.tar.gz
```

> Now you compile and install:

```
# cd /path/to/haveged-x.x
# ./configure
# make
# make install
```

> By default, this will install with a prefix of `/usr/local`, so you should add something similar to the following to `/etc/rc.local` (or your system's equivalent) to make it automatically start on boot (adjust the path if necessary):

```
# Autostart haveged
/usr/local/sbin/haveged -w 1024
```

> Run the same command manually (as root) to start the daemon without rebooting

---

#### Note: the current version is 1.9.1 as of today.

Comment: Is it recommended to use an entropy-boosting random-number generator like this nowadays?

Comment: @ewwhite - not 100% sure how "recommended" it is. It's certainly been performance-improving for me recently.

Comment: For what types of workloads?

Comment: @ewwhite lots of key generation (and running HP's Sever Automation somewhat better (as mentioned in this old [question](http://serverfault.com/q/303935/2321)))

Comment: @ewwhite - I've also noticed Apache being more responsive with SSL pages since adding the use of haveged